# Почему Double.TryParse выдает false?

Tags: c#, парсер, asp.net, double, преобразование-типов

У меня есть веб-форма, на которой произвожу выборку запроса.
в запросе переменная имеет значение 219.1. Я пытаюсь разобрать это следующим образом

```
double diam1 = 0;
if (rdr2.Read())
{
    Double.TryParse(rdr2["DIAMETER"].ToString(), out diam1);
}
```

Но метод выдает false и возвращает diam1 = 0, хотя по сути это должно работать, может кто-нибудь подсказать, в чем моя проблема? заранее спасибо

Comment: думаю, снова вопрос про текущую культуру. Поменяйте точку на запятую или в обратную сторону, или указывайте культуру явно при парсинге.

Comment: `Double.TryParse(rdr2["DIAMETER"].ToString(),NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out diam1)`

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо, это работает!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, снова вопрос про текущую культуру. Поменяйте точку на запятую или в обратную сторону, или указывайте культуру явно при парсинге.

```
Double.TryParse(rdr2["DIAMETER"].ToString(),
          NumberStyles.Any, 
          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
          out diam1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Используй перегруженную версию:

```
TryParse(String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider, Double)
```